# how to fix query-tool: Query failed ERROR: syntax error at or near while inserting data

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker

I have this command to populate created tables with geographic data

```
COPY public.adonis_schema (id, name, batch, migration_time) FROM stdin;
1   database/migrations/1607548129188_users 1   2021-04-02 14:14:27.470863+00
2   database/migrations/1607548416832_conversations 1   2021-04-02 14:14:28.070888+00
3   database/migrations/1607548444586_participations    1   2021-04-02 14:14:28.480253+00
4   database/migrations/1607548494088_messages  1   2021-04-02 14:14:29.050234+00
5   database/migrations/1609020554140_vcard_shares  1   2021-04-02 14:14:29.520909+00
6   database/migrations/1609024583459_add_conversation_names    1   2021-04-02 14:14:29.905367+00
7   database/migrations/1609467289494_meetings  1   2021-04-02 14:14:30.300248+00
8   database/migrations/1609467351706_notes 1   2021-04-02 14:14:30.960852+00
9   database/migrations/1609976010374_meetings_lengths  1   2021-04-02 14:14:31.640233+00
10  database/migrations/1610498049695_conversations_event_ids   1   2021-04-02 14:14:32.020247+00
11  database/migrations/1611099138751_cache_users   1   2021-04-02 14:14:32.405294+00
12  database/migrations/1616628109445_conversations_ownerships  1   2021-04-02 14:14:32.800258+00
13  database/migrations/1617362496376_conversations_types   1   2021-04-02 14:14:33.185207+00
14  database/migrations/1617805023298_conversations_timestamps  2   2021-04-07 14:18:42.957427+00
47  database/migrations/1622085675952_user_is_busies    3   2021-05-27 03:22:31.964783+00
\.
```

I have as indicated put the entire code in a sql file and executed it with psql but I have an error:

```
ERROR: ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « 1 »
LINE 2: 1 database/migrations/1607548129188_users 1 2021-04-02 14:14...
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 73
```

Do you have an idea please?

Comment: What client are you using? What is the database encoding?  Add answers as update to your question. `Character: 73` would be just before the `1` so I'm going to guess hidden character/encoding issue.

Comment: Is it possible the values aren't separated with the tab character, but with spaces?

Comment: I'm using pgadmin4. this is my link database

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=pg 
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@0.0.0.0:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable
CACHE_VIEWS=false

Comment: No separeted with tab character